# If I concede with a morph card on the stack, do I have to reveal the card to my opponent?

Tags: magic-the-gathering, mtg-face-down-cards

I understand that if a morph card is on the battlefield at the end of the game, I have to reveal it to my opponent, but what if my opponent responds to me casting the morph with a counterspell.  If I concede with the morph still on the stack, do I have to reveal it?

Comment: I wonder, you clearly read my answer to the other face-down question since you proposed an edit to it, what was unclear about the rule I quoted?

Comment: @Hackworth Re-reading the rule again, I guess the part i'm not clear on is the bit about 'face-down spell'.  Is it referring to a spell on the stack? Or is it referring to instants/sorceries that are face down in the battlefield?

Comment: "Spell" always implies a card on the stack, because spells can't exist anywhere else, see rule 111.1. On the battlefield, only permanents exist, not spells, see rule 110.1.

Comment: A spell is a card on the stack, or a copy of a card on the stack.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**Yes, you must reveal the card to all players.**

> 707.9. If a face-down permanent moves from the battlefield to any other zone, its owner must reveal it to all players as he or she moves it. If a face-down spell moves from the stack to any zone other than the battlefield, its owner must reveal it to all players as he or she moves it. **If a player leaves the game, all face-down permanents and spells owned by that player must be revealed to all players.** At the end of each game, all face-down permanents and spells must be revealed to all players.

The other players must be able to check that you were allowed to play that card face-down. Otherwise, you could cheat by playing a non-morph card as a morph creature and never be forced to reveal that card.

Comment: Thanks for bolding it, the third time reading the rule, with the explanation above, it is pretty clear.